# django - regex for optional url parameters

Tags: python, django, url-pattern, urlconf

I have a view in django that can accept a number of different filter parameters, but they are all optional.  If I have 6 optional filters, do I really have to write urls for every combination of the 6 or is there a way to define what parts of the url are optional?

To give you an example with just 2 filters, I could have all of these url possibilities:

```
/<city>/<state>/
/<city>/<state>/radius/<miles>/
/<city>/<state>/company/<company-name>/
/<city>/<state>/radius/<miles>/company/<company-name>/
/<city>/<state>/company/<company-name>/radius/<miles>/
```

All of these url's are pointing to the same view and the only required params are city and state.  With 6 filters, this becomes unmanageable.

What's the best way to go about doing what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One method would be to make the regular expression read all the given filters as a single string, and then split them up into individual values in the view.

I came up with the following URL:

```
(r'^(?P<city>[^/]+)/(?P<state>[^/]+)(?P<filters>(?:/[^/]+/[^/]+)*)/?$',
 'views.my_view'),
```

Matching the required city and state is easy. The `filters` part is a bit more complicated. The inner part - `(?:/[^/]+/[^/]+)*` - matches filters given in the form `/name/value`. However, the `*` quantifier (like all Python regular expression quantifiers) only returns the last match found - so if the url was `/radius/80/company/mycompany/` only `company/mycompany` would be stored. Instead, we tell it not to capture the individual values (the `?:` at the start), and put it inside a capturing block which will store all filter values as a single string.

The view logic is fairly straightforward. Note that the regular expression will only match pairs of filters - so `/company/mycompany/radius/` will not be matched. This means we can safely assume we have pairs of values. The view I tested this with is as follows:

```
def my_view(request, city, state, filters):
    # Split into a list ['name', 'value', 'name', 'value']. Note we remove the
    # first character of the string as it will be a slash.
    split = filters[1:].split('/')

    # Map into a dictionary {'name': 'value', 'name': 'value'}.
    filters = dict(zip(split[::2], split[1::2]))

    # Get the values you want - the second parameter is the default if none was
    # given in the URL. Note all entries in the dictionary are strings at this
    # point, so you will have to convert to the appropriate types if desired.
    radius = filters.get('radius', None)
    company = filters.get('company', None)

    # Then use the values as desired in your view.
    context = {
        'city': city,
        'state': state,
        'radius': radius,
        'company': company,
    }
    return render_to_response('my_view.html', context)
```

Two things to note about this. First, it allows unknown filter entries into your view. For example, `/fakefilter/somevalue` is valid. The view code above ignores these, but you probably want to report an error to the user. If so, alter the code getting the values to

```
radius = filters.pop('radius', None)
company = filters.pop('company', None)
```

Any entries remaining in the `filters` dictionary are unknown values about which you can complain.

Second, if the user repeats a filter, the last value will be used. For example, `/radius/80/radius/50` will set the radius to 50. If you want to detect this, you will need to scan the list of values before it is converted to a dictionary:

```
given = set()
for name in split[::2]:
    if name in given:
        # Repeated entry, complain to user or something.
    else:
        given.add(name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and great answer!  The only thing that seems to not work a 100%, is that the values returned all have a colon ":" on the end of them.

Comment: Hmmmm, I didn't notice that when testing it here. Can you give an example of a URL that does this?

Answer (score 8):

This is absolutely the use-case for GET parameters. Your urlconf should just be `/city/state/`, then the various filters go on the end as GET variables:

```
/city/state/?radius=5&company=google
```

Now, in your view, you accept `city` and `state` as normal parameters, but everything else is stored in the `request.GET` QueryDict.

Answer (score 2):

You could also make just one url (that only checks the start of the path, that should be the same) pointing to your view and then parse `request.path` in your view. 
On the other hand, if you have really many optional filter parameters in various combinations the best solution is very often to do th filtering via `GET`-parameters, especially if the urls used for filtering don't need to be optimized for any search engine...

Answer (score -1):

Try use something like that in your urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<city>[^/]+)/(?P<state>[^/]+)/(radius/(?P<miles>[^/]+)/|company/(?P<company_name>[^/]+)/)*$', 'view')
```

Comment: Will Django be able to reverse that URL? That may not be relevant in bababa's case...

Comment: yeah, I know I probably won't be able to use reverse for this view, but that's ok for my situation.