# django urls optimization

Tags: django

urls with 2 request params:

/prefix1/1/ 
/prefix2/2/ 
/prefix1/1/prefix2/2 
/prefix2/2/prefix1/1

```
url( ur'^prefix1/(?P<p1>\d+)/$', 'app.views.view' ),
url( ur'^prefix2/(?P<p2>\d+)/$', 'app.views.view' ),
url( ur'^prefix1/(?P<p1>\d+)/prefix2/(?P<p2>\d+)/$', 'app.views.view' ),
url( ur'^prefix2/(?P<p2>\d+)/prefix1/(?P<p1>\d+)/$', 'app.views.view' ),
```

Is possible to do this more 'DRY' (with 3 request params, lines in `urls.py` = 15) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399035/django-regex-for-optional-url-paramaters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hacked together a sample and, if lazerscience's comment doesn't do it for you, here's what I came up with:

```
url(r'^(?P<param1>foo|bar)(/(?P<param2>\d+))?(/(?P<param3>\d+))?(/(?P<param4>\d+))?/$', 'demo.views.view'),
```

And my view looked like:

```
def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render_to_response("index.html",
        { 'dict': [(k, v) for k,v in kwargs.iteritems()] },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It progressively added parameters as you added to the url, left to right, just as you'd expect.

Comment: not exactly that i nee, you forgot about `prefix`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399035/django-regex-for-optional-url-paramaters/5399101#5399101

Comment: No, I didn't.  I assumed you knew enough to be able to derive an equivalent prefix from the `foo|bar` example expression above.